# How can I pass data to a GAE base template?

Tags: google-app-engine, inheritance, django-templates

Using Google App Engines webapp framework, is there any way to pass data to a base template?
To be specific, I just want a logout button to be visible if the user is logged on (using googles own authentication system).

I'm still learning so I'm not sure what parts are GAE specific and what parts are django specific; having to send the logged in user from every single request handler seems very un-DRY.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arguments to base templates are passed the same way as any other template arguments, by being passed to template.render. I usually solve this by having a convenience method on my base handler that inserts common template arguments, like this:

```
class BaseHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def render_template(self, filename, template_args):
    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates', filename)
    template_args.update({
        'user': users.get_current_user(),
        # ...
    })

class MyHandler(BaseHandler):
  def get(self):
    self.render_template('my.html', {'foo': 'bar'})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like [login_required decorator in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889622/login-required-decorator-in-django). You can either try to use a complete [django framework in GAE](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries.html#Django) (I never tried) or it can be customized easily with [decoration](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/498217-custom-django-login_required-decorator/) and add your own behavior. In your case, it will be a good idea to pass user's login status to template engine.

```
#the decorator
def login_checked(f):
    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        # get current user
        user = get_current_user()
        template_path, vars = f(request, *args, **kwargs)           
        vars['user']= user
        template.render(template_path, vars)
    return wrap

# usage
class MyPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    @login_checked # add a decoration 
    def get(self):
        # your page       
        return "the_template_page_you_want", {"the value you want to pass to template": "xxx"}
```

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at this example:

```
from google.appengine.api import users

class MyHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        user = users.get_current_user()
        if user:
            greeting = ("Welcome, %s! (<a href=\"%s\">sign out</a>)" %
                        (user.nickname(), users.create_logout_url("/")))
        else:
            greeting = ("<a href=\"%s\">Sign in or register</a>." %
                        users.create_login_url("/"))

        self.response.out.write("<html><body>%s</body></html>" % greeting)
```

Source: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/loginurls.html

Comment: Since the question is explicitly about templates, this really isn't helpful.